# XML to java Object conversion using simpleframework

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am converting  xml file to java object using simpleframework. I am using generics since my xml's internal nodes gets changing. But simpleframework throws an error while converting. Here is my sample code:

```
@Root(name = "searchresult", strict = false)
public class ResponseVO<T>
{
    @ElementList(entry = "document", inline = true)
    public List<T> elementVOList = new ArrayList<T>();

    public List<T>  getElementsVOList()
    {
        return elementVOList;
    }

    public void setElementsVOList(List<T>list)
    {
        elementVOList = list;
    }
}
```

ResponseVO is container for various other VOs as below:

```
@Root(name = "document", strict = false)
public class Projects_Display_VO
{

    @Element(name = "projectname")
    private String projectName;


    @Attribute(name = "id")
    private int tmpid;

    public int getTmpid()
    {
        return tmpid;
    }

    public void setTmpid(int tmpid)
    {
        this.tmpid = tmpid;
    }
    /**
     * ProjectId
     */

    @Element(name = "projectid")
    private String projectID;


    public String getProjectName()
    {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName)
    {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    public int getProjectID()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(projectID);
    }

    public void setProjectID(String projectID)
    {
        this.projectID = projectID;
    }
}
```

And the **XML file** is as below:

```
<searchresult>
  <query>id:(PROJ2 PROJ6)</query>
  <document id="0">
    <projectid>2</projectid>
    <projectname>Redundant Demo Project</projectname>
    <doctype>Projects</doctype>
    <summary>||Demo Project</summary>
    <title>Redundant Demo Project</title>
  </document>
  <document id="1">
    <projectid>6</projectid>
    <projectname>Redundant Demo Project2</projectname>
    <doctype>Projects</doctype>
    <summary>||Main terminal links.</summary>
    <title>Terminal 5 Project</title>
  </document>  
</searchresult>
```

The code for conversion is as bellow:

```
ResponseVO<Projects_Display_VO> resp = (ResponseVO<Projects_Display_VO>)  SerializationUtil.deserialize(ResponseVO.class, reader);
```

Here i am using serializer from simpleframework. But it throws following error

```
Exception::Attribute 'id' does not have a match in class java.lang.Object at line 5
org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute 'id' does not have a match in   class java.lang.Object at line 5
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readAttribute(Composite.java:555)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readAttributes(Composite.java:474)
at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readSection(Composite.java:387)
```

I dont know whats going wrong here.A it works fine without generics.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by erasure, T is not available at runtime. Java does not allow it.